# Why my Right Join does not get me the Region West?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this dataset
https://dbfiddle.uk/wtbPEvoE

like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #RegionSales
(
Region       VARCHAR(100),
Distributor  VARCHAR(100),
Sales        INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (Region, Distributor)
);

INSERT INTO #RegionSales VALUES
('North','ACE',10),
('South','ACE',67),
('East','ACE',54),
('North','Direct Parts',8),
('South','Direct Parts',7),
('West','Direct Parts',12),
('North','ACME',65),
('South','ACME',9),
('East','ACME',1),
('West','ACME',7);

WITH cte as (
              SELECT distinct region 
              FROM #RegionSales )

SELECT * 
FROM      #RegionSales as rs
RIGHT JOIN cte                    ON rs.Region = cte.Region
WHERE Distributor = 'ACE'
```

Can someone understand why I do not get the Region West from the CTE?
The right join should give me the following data:

[image]

Comment: Because distribute `ACE` does not exist in region `West`.

Comment: Yes, i know. But it exists in the cte_Table and the right join should give me this.

Comment: I always thouth that a right join also give me the non connectably party.

Comment: `SELECT FROM A RIGHT JOIN B` is just another way to say `SELECT FROM B LEFT JOIN A`. This is true whether A and B are single tables or working sets in a more complex query.  You're almost always better off writing the LEFT JOIN version of the query.

Comment: Yes, but your WHERE clause means that it will only keep JOIN results where `Distributor='ACE'`.

Comment: @TimRoberts you right tim. First the Join then the WHERE

Comment: I forgot that the join is always BEFORE the WHERE

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to do this:

```sql
WITH cte as (
              SELECT distinct region 
              FROM #RegionSales )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN #RegionSales rs ON rs.Region = cte.Region AND rs.Distributor='ACE';
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/lffS9hO3)

Because when doing a `RIGHT JOIN` like this:

```sql
WITH cte as (
              SELECT distinct region 
              FROM #RegionSales )
SELECT * 
FROM #RegionSales rs
RIGHT JOIN cte ON rs.Region = cte.Region ;
```

You will not get any Region/Distribute with values `West/ACE`, see [DBFIDDLE2](https://dbfiddle.uk/CKm4fL6Z)

Comment: yes. But why the right join does not working? Should also working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go:

```
   WITH cte as (
                  SELECT distinct region 
                  FROM RegionSales )

SELECT *
FROM      RegionSales as rs
RIGHT JOIN cte                    ON rs.Region = cte.Region AND rs.Distributor = 'ACE'
```